# When chosen, Adobe Reader opens another app when sent an Intent to view a PDF - is this my bug or theirs?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an application with a snippet of code that should open up a PDF in an appropriate PDF reader. When starting the activity with the Intent, I am presented with an app chooser as expected, and then the app opens as expected. However with [Adobe Reader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adobe.reader), this breaks, and I can't tell if this is my fault or a bug with Adobe.

Here's the snippet of code that creates and launches the Intent:

```kotlin
// Set up URI for file using FileProvider
val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
    context,
    "${BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID}.provider",
    file.getPath(context)
)

// Get the extension of the file and mimetype
val extension = File(fileName).extension
val mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension)

// Set up intent to view the file in an external app with read only permission
val viewIntent = Intent().apply {
    action = Intent.ACTION_VIEW
    setDataAndType(uri, mime)
    addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
}

// Fire away!
context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(viewIntent, null))
```

The behaviour that I experience is that Adobe launches, and then immediately launches another application on my device called [3CX](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tcx.sipphone14). 3CX understandably shows a toast saying it can't handle the file.

Other PDF readers all seem to work, although I haven't tried very extensively all third party applications available.

Does anyone have any idea if this is a me-issue, or and Adobe issue?